On exact differential equation
An equation of the form
$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$
Is said to be exactly differential if there exists a function $F(x,y)$ such that
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=M $$ and $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=N $$
Now, I am trying to show why does,
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$
Implies that the given differential equation is exact?
All my attempts showed nothing, so I am not mentioning them here.

You should mention your attempts here, so that we can help you further, one of them may be a proof after writing a few more things, which you could not find.

You are looking for the Poincare lemma and you also need the assumption that you are trying to solve that exact DE on a star-shaped (convex or simply connected will also do the trick).
Let us assume that
$$
f=Mdx+Ndy
$$
satisfies
$$
dF=\partial_x F dx+ \partial_y Fdy=f.
$$
Then, applying $d$ again to $dF$ yiels
\begin{align*}
ddF&=(\partial_y M - \partial_x N)dx \wedge dy \\
 &=(\partial_{yx}F-\partial_{xy}F) dx \wedge dy \\
&=0
\end{align*}
if $F$ is $C^2$ by the Schwarz lemma. So we have established that being exact implies your condition
$$
\partial_y M=\partial_x N.
$$
The converse is true on star-shaped (again, convex or simply connected is fine too) domains. That means the equation above implies that $f$ is exact and hence your DE is exact.
